# How to clear Weather location on Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME)

Tags: gnome, 18.04, calendar, privacy, weather

On my Ubuntu 18.04 system with GNOME 3.28 on it I have set in the top-panel's calendar pull-down the weather location so it checks with the `gnome-weather` application the weather information for my given area.

However due to partly privacy concerns and also no use for it I would like to get it to stop doing that. However the `gnome-weather` interface only seem to allow a change of location, but not a deletion and a stopping use of the application altogether.

I don't want to have to remove the application, is there a "friendly" way of doing this or do I have to edit a config file or something?

Comment: Does `gsettings reset org.gnome.GWeather default-location` work?

Comment: @pomsky: Will that require me to restart the GNOME session?

Comment: Not sure, try restarting once to be safe.

Comment: @pomsky: No, that does not work.

Comment: @cl-netbox No, I have 3.28, but I don't have GWeather installed in the first place :D It was a guesswork.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute this command, it will clear all the locations from `gnome-weather`:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.Weather.Application locations
```

In case you prefer a GUI solution, you can install and use `dconf-editor` to achieve the same.

Update : Meanwhile the command has changed ... Thank you @bela83 for your information ! :)

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.Weather locations
```

Comment: With `20.04` it looks like the command now reads `gsettings reset org.gnome.Weather locations`.